# How to list IDs with the lowest score when comparing to associate ‘friend’ IDs where one ID is associated with many?

Tags: sql

Based on the structure below, I am trying to write a query that would show me which student scored lower than any of their listed friends.

The friend ID correlates to the Student ID as well. So Student 1 = Friend 1.

Expected output should be 3 and 4 in this case.

```
Expected Output
+---------+
| Student |
+---------+
|        1|
+---------+


Relationships
+---------+--------+
| Student | Friend |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      3 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       3 |      4 |
|       3 |      1 |
|       4 |      2 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |      5 |
+---------+--------+

Scores
+---------+------+
| Student | Exam |
+---------+------+
|       1 |   90 |
|       2 |   90 |
|       3 |   80 |
|       4 |   30 |
|       5 |   69 |
|       6 |   50 |
+---------+------+
```

Been running some random projects, test, and homework to learn more.
But I am completely stuck on this one.

I tried a sub query to list the highest friend and then to compare student score vs friend score and the other idea was to rejoin the the tables again on the Friend ID.

Unfortunately both just got the best of me.

Looking for guidance on this, please and thank you!

EDIT1: added expected output in table format
EDIT2: Most solutions given are working, I also wanted to share my initial trial which does work as well, but isn't the easy way to do it.

```
with data as (
SELECT
  r.student
  ,case when a.Exam < ex.Exam then 1 else 0 end as Score
FROM Relationships r
JOIN Scores s on r.student = s.student
JOIN (
    SELECT Min(Exam) as Exam
    ,friend
    ,r.Student
    FROM Relationships r
    JOIN Scores s on r.friend = s.Student
    GROUP BY ,friend ,r.Student
    ) ex on ex.Student = r.Student
GROUP BY r.Student
)

Select Student
FROM data
GROUP BY Student
```

Comment: could you please add your expected output in table format

Comment: What do you mean by "which student scored lower than any of their listed friends"?  To me that sounds like the student that scored lower than ALL of their listed fired, but the sentence is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `join`

```
select
    r.student  
from relationships r

join scores s
on r.student = s.student

join scores s1
on r.friend = s1.student

where s.exam < s1.exam
```

output:

```
| student | 
| ------- | 
| 3       |
| 4       |
```

Comment: My rep is too low, but I believe this was the best answer. I noticed I wrote lowest in the title, but 'lower score' in the description. This one works best for me. Dang, it just seem so easy now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using s subqiery for min exam  joined  with your Relationships

```
select r.Student
FROM Relationships r 
INNER JOIN Scores s2  on r.Student = s2.Student
INNER JOIN (
    select r.Student, min(s1.exam) min_exam
    FROM Relationships r 
    INNER JOIN Scores s1  on r.Friend = s1.Student
    group by  r.Student

    ) t on t.Student = r.Student 
        and s2.exam < t.min_exam
```

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to process this, but it works!

Comment: is there something you don't understand ??

Comment: I understand it now! I am just still to novice :\